# Passing Map from Apex server controller to Lightning controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to use the wrapper class variables values in my jscontroller and please help me

I have a

```
public Map<String,FinancialSummary> reservesSummaryHeader{}
```

In which I am using wrapper class as values so how can i access that wrapper class values using that MAP key

This is my APex class-

```
public with sharing class ClaimsController1 {

     @AuraEnabled   
    public static Map<String,FinancialSummary> getallRecord(){
        ClaimsController1 obj = new ClaimsController1();


         return obj.reservesSummary;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public Map<String,List<String>> transactionTypesMap{
        get{
            if(transactionTypesMap == NULL){
                transactionTypesMap = new Map<String,List<String>>();
                for(Selectoption sp : Utils.getPicklistValues('Reserve_Level_2__c', 'Financials__c')){                  
                    String mainLevel = sp.getValue().substringBefore('-');                  
                    if(!transactionTypesMap.containsKey(mainLevel)){
                        transactionTypesMap.put(mainLevel,new List<String>());                      
                    }
                    transactionTypesMap.get(mainLevel).add(sp.getValue());                  
                }
            }
            return transactionTypesMap;
        }
        set;
    }

    @AuraEnabled    
    public Map<String,Decimal> paymentsSummaryHeader {
        get{
            if(paymentsSummaryHeader == null){          
            paymentsSummaryHeader = new Map<String,Decimal>();
            for(String opt : transactionTypesMap.keySet()){
                    if(!paymentsSummaryHeader.containsKey(opt)){
                        paymentsSummaryHeader.put(opt,0.00);
                    }
                }
                for(AggregateResult agr :[SELECT Reserve_Main__c,SUM(Amount__c) total_Amount FROM Financials__c 
                                                WHERE Claim__c=:'a009000003aE68L' AND RecordType.DeveloperName='Payment' GROUP BY Reserve_Main__c]){
                    paymentsSummaryHeader.put((String)agr.get('Reserve_Main__c'),(Decimal)agr.get('total_Amount'));         
                }           
            }
            return paymentsSummaryHeader;
        }
        set;
    }

     @AuraEnabled
     public Map<String,Decimal> paymentsSummary {
        get{
            if(paymentsSummary == null){            
                paymentsSummary = new Map<String,Decimal>();
                for(String mainOpt : transactionTypesMap.keySet()){
                    for(String lowerOpt : transactionTypesMap.get(mainOpt)){
                        if(!paymentsSummary.containsKey(lowerOpt)){
                            paymentsSummary.put(lowerOpt,0.00);
                        }                       
                    }
                }           
                for(AggregateResult agr :[SELECT Reserve_Level_2__c,SUM(Amount__c) total_Amount FROM Financials__c 
                                                WHERE Claim__c=:'a009000003aE68L' AND RecordType.DeveloperName='Payment' GROUP BY Reserve_Level_2__c]){
                    paymentsSummary.put((String)agr.get('Reserve_Level_2__c'),(Decimal)agr.get('total_Amount'));            
                }           
            }
        return paymentsSummary;
        }
        set;
    }   

    @AuraEnabled
    public Map<String,FinancialSummary> reservesSummaryHeader {
        get{            
            if(reservesSummaryHeader == NULL){
                reservesSummaryHeader = new Map<String,FinancialSummary>();
                for(String opt : transactionTypesMap.keySet()){
                    if(!reservesSummaryHeader.containsKey(opt)){
                        reservesSummaryHeader.put(opt,new FinancialSummary());
                    }
                }
                for(AggregateResult agr :[SELECT Reserve_Main__c,SUM(Amount__c) total_Amount FROM Financials__c 
                                                WHERE Claim__c=:'a009000003aE68L' AND RecordType.DeveloperName='Estimate' AND is_Reserve_Reduction__c=false GROUP BY Reserve_Main__c]){
                    String type = (String)agr.get('Reserve_Main__c');
                    reservesSummaryHeader.put(type,new FinancialSummary(agr.get('total_Amount'),paymentsSummaryHeader.get(type)));
                }
            }
            return reservesSummaryHeader;               
        }
        set;
    }   

    @AuraEnabled
    public Map<String,FinancialSummary> reservesSummary {
        get{
            if(reservesSummary == NULL){
                reservesSummary = new Map<String,FinancialSummary>();
                for(String mainOpt : transactionTypesMap.keySet()){
                    for(String lowerOpt : transactionTypesMap.get(mainOpt)){
                        if(!reservesSummary.containsKey(lowerOpt)){
                            reservesSummary.put(lowerOpt,new FinancialSummary());
                        }                       
                    }

                }
                 //system.debug('Hello123'+reservesSummary);
                for(AggregateResult agr :[SELECT Reserve_Level_2__c,SUM(Amount__c) total_Amount FROM Financials__c 
                                                WHERE Claim__c=:'a009000003aE68L' AND RecordType.DeveloperName='Estimate' AND is_Reserve_Reduction__c=false GROUP BY Reserve_Level_2__c]){
                    String type = (String)agr.get('Reserve_Level_2__c');

                    reservesSummary.put(type,new FinancialSummary(agr.get('total_Amount'),paymentsSummary.get(type)));

                }
                // 
            }
            system.debug('hellLokesh'+reservesSummary.keySet());
            return reservesSummary;             
        }
        set;
    }



     //Sub Class for Summary display
    public class FinancialSummary{
        //public String reserveCode; 
        public Decimal balanceAmount {get; set;}
        public Decimal totalAmount {get; set;}      
        public Decimal newValue {get; set;}
        public Decimal totalPaidAmount {get; set;}

        public FinancialSummary(Object amount,Object paidAmount){//String reserveCode,
            //this.reserveCode = reserveCode;
            this.totalAmount = (Decimal)amount;
            this.totalPaidAmount = (Decimal) paidAmount;
            this.newValue = 0.00;
            this.balanceAmount = this.totalAmount != null ? (this.totalAmount - (Decimal) paidAmount) : 0.00;


        }
        public FinancialSummary(){
            this.balanceAmount = 0.00;
            this.totalAmount = 0.00;
            this.newValue = 0.00;
            this.totalPaidAmount = 0.00;
            //this.reserveCode = NULL;
        }
    }


}
```

and this is my js Controller

```
({
      doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
     //call apex class method
    var action = component.get('c.getallRecord');
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        //store state of response
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
           //Create an empty array to store the map keys 
                var arrayMapKeys = [];
                //Store the response of apex controller (return map)     
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                //Set the store response[map] to component attribute, which name is map and type is map.   
                component.set('v.mapValues', result);

                for (var key in result) {
                    arrayMapKeys.push(key);
                    console.log('hello12'+result[key]);
                    var dbh = result[key];
                    console.log('hello12'+JSON.stringify(dbh));
                }
                //Set the list of keys.     
                component.set('v.mapKeyList', arrayMapKeys);
            //component.set('v.objClassController',JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
        }
   });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

Comment: What issue are you having? You seem to have written code to do this.

Comment: How many accounts do you have? Please refrain from having multiple accounts

Answer (score 3):

The attributes need to be @AuraEnabled. A getter/setter will not help you here.

```
    @AuraEnabled public Decimal balanceAmount;
    @AuraEnabled public Decimal totalAmount;
    @AuraEnabled public Decimal newValue;
    @AuraEnabled public Decimal totalPaidAmount;
```

You can read more about it in [Returning Data from an Apex Server-Side Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm).